# eclipse error while showing console view starting

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

how to remove this kind of error from eclipse?

[image]

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory and see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question and add the details.

Answer (score 1):

Close the "Console" tab from views, then go to Windows -> Show View -> Console. Sometimes the listener code for Console view gets crazy and start throwing exceptions.